# PHP array to C# List

Tags: c#, php, arrays, wcf, soap

After submitting a form in my PHP application I store some values in an array like this

```
     if(isset($_POST['submitArticle']))
        {
            $artikel = $_POST['article'];
            $aantal = $_POST['quantity'];
            $a=0;

            $art = array();
            $quan = array();

            foreach($artikel as $key => $value)
            {
                $art[] = $artikel[$a];
                $quan[] = $aantal[$a];

                $a++;
            }
            $artikelArguments = array_combine($art, $quan);
```

Now I call a method in my C# application with my new array as an argument:

```
$client->getArticle($artikelArguments);
```

My method in C# looks something like this:

```
    public List<string> getArticle(List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> articles)
            {
               //Get articles based on ID
               foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> art in articles)
               {
```

Now articles is always null, so the values won't get passed, or C# can't handle my PHP array. Does someone have any suggestions?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault]
```

Comment: Perhaps it cannot convert it to `List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>`, I would start by changing it to `object` and ensure that your c# method gets called.

Comment: I used object at first since PHP returns lousy variables but my WCF service can't handle that.

Comment: How does the `WSDL` for the `getArticle` operation look? Can you post the `wsdl:operation` tag contains?

Comment: You mean this? <wsdl:operation name="getArticle"><wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IIQService/getArticle" message="tns:IIQService_getArticle_InputMessage"/><wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IIQService/getArticleResponse" message="tns:IIQService_getArticle_OutputMessage"/></wsdl:operation>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that this didnt get a proper answer. For this issue I used objects instead of integers and then it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

This is not answering directly your question, but whenever I have to make soap calls from php, I use a proxy generator, such as the one you can find [there](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6781-PHP-Generate-code-to-access-SOAP-services-from-an-WSDL.html), developped by Przemek Berezowski. It'll handle soap type conversion for you